# 12 V / 24 V power using series & parallel circuit of 12 V batteries. Is this viable?

Tags: batteries, parallel, series

Is this a viable layout?

The 12 V system is for everyday use on a boat. This boat system is 12 V. The charging is to the 12 V system.

There is no permanent 24 V system. The 24 V would only be used intermittently to operate a 24 V windlass (used to raise the anchor). 24 V is needed because of the long run from the battery to the windlass (less amperage smaller wires).

[image: wiring diagram]

Comment: Well, you'd better not close S3 at the same time as either S1 or S2 for one thing as you'd have a dead short on B2 and B1 respectively! So assuming you just intend S3 to be closed for 24V, that wouldn't work, either. B1 would be completely disconnected (S1&S2 open) and the dotted line would be an inconsequential loop round the -ve of B2 with no PD anywhere in it (with scenic stop-off on the +ve of V1).

Comment: Put a second 12V battery under the foredeck. It should be OK to charge it via those wires.

Comment: Thanks for the reply

Comment: Most boats I know have a separate battery near the anchor windlass that's charged from the engine alternator (or other means of charging) via the main battery bank, as @user_1818839 already noted. Your solution looks much more complex and (more importantly) dangerous when not used correctly (for example by someone on board that does not understand the switching  procedure or when needed in an emergency). Keep stuff simple onboard (K.I.S.S).

Answer (score 1):

You've connected S3 across the wrong battery terminals.  The way you've drawn it, you will get 0V.

Ideally, you want to make the whole thing a (very substantial) single rotary switch.  S1 and S2 should be turned on and off together.  And you need to ensure that S3 is off when S1 and S2 are on, and vice-versa.  Use separate switches, and any mistake as to what order you operate the switches in will end up with burning wires.  A 12V lead-acid battery can produce huge currents when short circuited.

Comment: ... and do so within a fraction of a second.

Answer (score 1):

S3 should be connected from B2+ to B1-.  Your 24V connection is correct.

This could be very hazardous if you operated the switches in the wrong order.  I would want a mechanical interlock to ensure that S1 and S2 operate together, and cannot be closed if S3 is closed, and S3 cannot be closed if S1 and S2 are closed.

Comment: The whole thing is a bad idea, I think, but I think you're right in what was intended. They have to be different switches and you'd need to be super sure of the break/make sequence guarantees of any double pole switches used.

Comment: Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 1):

Something like this may work.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOtTcD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks  for the design

Comment: Since the problem is the current demand of an anchor winch, that had better be one hefty relay.